# How to add footprint parameter into ODATA API query (Sentinel-hub search)?

Tags: api, sentinel-hub

As mentioned in the FAQ about [OData API](https://scihub.copernicus.eu/twiki/do/view/SciHubUserGuide/ODataAPI) usage I can perform such queries to search Sentinel-2 scenes:

[https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products?$format=json&$filter=startswith(Name,'S2') and ContentDate/Start ge datetime'2018-08-25T00:00:00' and ContentDate/End le datetime'2018-08-26T00:00:00'](https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products?$format=json&$filter=startswith(Name,'S2')%20and%20ContentDate/Start%20ge%20datetime'2018-08-25T00:00:00'%20and%20ContentDate/End%20le%20datetime'2018-08-26T00:00:00')

But I still don’t understand how to add footprint search parameter into this query, because there is no clean examples in the FAQ, only mentioned `/Products` properties:

> ContentGeometry   footprint polygon coordinates in GML format

I am asking for few examples how to query Sentinel-2 scenes using point/polygon coordinates with ODATA API.

Comment: Have you tried to add in the end of the query : `and ContentGeomety '<gml:Polygon><gml:outerBoundaryIs><gml:LinearRing><gml:coordinates>0,0 100,0 100,100 0,100 0,0</gml:coordinates></gml:LinearRing></gml:outerBoundaryIs></gml:Polygon>'` ?

Comment: @J.Monticolo I recive this: "Invalid filter expression: 'startswith(Name,'S2') and ContentDate/Start ge datetime'2018-08-25T00:00:00' and ContentDate/End le datetime'2018-08-26T00:00:00' and ContentGeomety '<gml:Polygon><gml:outerBoundaryIs><gml:LinearRing><gml:coordinates>0,0 100,0 100,100 0,100 0,0</gml:coordinates></gml:LinearRing></gml:outerBoundaryIs></gml:Polygon>''."

Comment: @J.Monticolo If you are an ODATA API user please give examples of how you request scenes by coordinates.

Comment: I'm not an ODATA user, I just had a look to the syntax and tried to guess how it could be work.